# How to get Liferay current url that is being displayed in browser?

Tags: liferay

I have two portlets on a page "Portlet A" and "Portlet B".
The page has url http://localhost:8080/web/guest/page?p_p_id="Portlet A"...
Then I submit a form in "Portlet B" and try to get current url from PortalUtil like

```
PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(myRequest);//p_p_id="Portlet B"...
themeDisplay.getURLCurrent(myRequest);p_p_id="Portlet B"...
```

But in browser before submission I see url with p_p_id="Portlet A"...

Is there a way to get url that is being shown to user?

Comment: The URL before submission is called the _referrer_ - because it is the source of the request. The _current URL_ is the one that is the target of the request.

Comment: Thank you Tobias this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link I was looking for is called *Referer* and points to the page where the request comes from.
Thanks to [Tobias Liefke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4371659/tobias-liefke)

In Liferay you can find it using `portlerRequest.getHttpRequest().getHeader("Referer")`

Comment: Just as a remark: some browsers and some addons suppress the referrer - so it is not always available.